# What is an alternative to @Transactional(readOnly=true) for read only queries in Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring with Hibernate. I have some queries that don't actually need a transaction, but I'm using one because it does the session management for me. What is the correct way of doing these non-transactional read queries without doing my own session management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @Transaction(readOnly=true) **is** the right way to do it. That's not going to create a new/extra physical transaction, so there shouldn't be any overhead to using that. It's going to use the transaction that was already set up for the request. Per the Hibernate docs:

> ... in fact, every SQL statement, be it queries or DML, has to execute inside a database transaction. There can be no communication with a database outside of a database transaction. (Note that there are such things as read-only transactions, that can be used to improve cleanup time in a database engine if it is not smart enough to optimize its own operations.)

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions#Transactions

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can work without transactions with database (well, there is, but it's a rare case that driver supports NO_TRANSACTION mode like DB2 driver). Moreover, drivers and databases may not support read-only transactions (like Oracle). So even if underlying connection was set to read-only mode, this doesn't mean it will have effect.

The only thing that is for sure about read-only flag in this case is that it will set Hibernate's flush mode to MANUAL. This means that Hibernate won't synchronize with database unless explicit call to Session#flush() was issued. So no dirty checks and no inserts/updates/selects will be issued in the end of transaction.

For more precise information on transaction management you can take a look at `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager#doBegin()` method.